# Take one string variable and use it in an 'IN' statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which accepts a **parameter** called `p_my_list_of_numbers`. This is a comma delimited **string** which looks something like this `'1,4,5,8,9,22,89'`.

```
 PROCEDURE my_procedure ( p_my_list_of_numbers VARCHAR2)
 BEGIN

       SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID IN (1,4,5,8,9,22,89); //THIS RETURNS DATA
       SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE ID IN p_my_list_of_numbers; //DOES NOT RETURN ANYTHING

 END;
```

How can I take this one long string and be able to use it in the select query so that it returns data?

Comment: You can either create dynamic SQL and execute it, or you have to split and insert the values into a temporary table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following sub-query:

```
select regexp_substr('1,4,5,8,9,22,89','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
connect by regexp_substr('1,4,5,8,9,22,89', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

This splits the list of comma separated values into a result set. Your procedure would look similar to this:

```
 PROCEDURE my_procedure ( p_my_list_of_numbers VARCHAR2)
 BEGIN

       SELECT * FROM my_table 
       WHERE ID IN (
          select regexp_substr(p_my_list_of_numbers,'[^,]+', 1, level) 
          from dual
          connect by regexp_substr(p_my_list_of_numbers, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null); 

 END;
```

Of course, you might want to validate your input, but I assume this was just a sample procedure for your question.